# Include external HTML file using native JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I want to include my external HTML file using JS but without using Jquery.  **I have used this but its not working without Jquery.**

```
<script>
$(function() {
    $('#filename').load("filename.html");
});
</script>
```

Is there any better solution with you Guys?

Comment: Why do you expect jQuery selectors to work without jQuery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery's `load()` is based on `get()` which is based on `$.ajax` which is based on the native `XMLHttpRequest`.

```
var req = new XMLHttpRequest();

req.onload = function() {
    document.getElementById('filename').innerHTML = this.responseText;
}

req.open("get", "filename.html", true);
req.send();
```